# Как сделать выпадающий список в yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Как сделать выпадающий список в yii2 на основе ActiveForm и модели? В yii был метод listData

```
CHtml::dropDownList(
    'categories',
    $category,
    CHtml::listData(
        Categories::model()->findAll("Status=1"), 'id', 'name'
    )
);
```

Сейчас в Html нет такого

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use backend\models\Standard;
?>

<?= Html::activeDropDownList(
        $category,
        'categories',
        ArrayHelper::map(
            Categories::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'
        )
    ) ?>
```

В Yii2 на замену списков с данными `CHtml` приходит `ArrayHelper`.

Answer (score -2):

Вот тут подробно рассмотрена работа с dropdownlist http://web-sprints.ru/yii2-dropdownlist-vyipadayushhiy-spisok/

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.